# variable expansion as a pattern in sed not working

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, sed

I've a simple script to set several parameters in /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a param=('Banner' 'ClientAliveInterval' 'ClientAliveCountMax' 'Ciphers' \
'PermitUserEnvironment' 'PermitEmptyPasswords' 'PermitRootLogin' \
'HostbasedAuthentication' 'IgnoreRhosts' 'MaxAuthTries' \
'X11Forwarding' 'LogLevel'\
)

declare -a val=('/etc/issue.net' '300' '0' 'aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr' \
'no' 'no' 'no' 'no' 'yes' '4' 'no' 'INFO' \
)

for (( i=0;i<12;i++ ))
do
 #echo "${param[$i]} ${val[$i]}"
  egrep "^[ #]*${param[$i]}.*" /etc/ssh/sshd_config &> /dev/null
   if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
       sed -i "s|^[ #]*\$param[$i].*|${param[$i]} ${val[$i]}|1" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  else
       echo "${param[$i]} ${val[$i]}" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  fi
done;
```

However the variable expansion in sed pattern match is not working as desired:

```
sed -i "s|^[ #]*\$param[$i].*|${param[$i]} ${val[$i]}|1" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Can someone help me. My array expansion and everything in the script is fine though. I've checked the same with an `echo` printout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have `$` escaped, and to access array element you need to use `${param[$i]}`.

You can use:

```
sed -i "s~^[ #]*${param[$i]}.*~${param[$i]} ${val[$i]}~1" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

btw `^[ #]*` will only match space or `#` at line start.

Comment: Great..thanks, it works. However one more query just so I understand it right. Basic `sed` syntax for search and replace would be: `sed 's/pattern/change_to/g' file`. But in your response I see `~` instead. More so it's `s~`. Can you kindly explain that a bit. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I used `~` since `sed` allows any character as regex delimiter and `~` was not seen in your search text.